# Java Exceptions - Important?

Tags: java

I had a lecture today where the professor reviewed basic Object-oriented concepts in Java. At one point, she said that "Exceptions are extremely important to your code, you need to handle all possible cases."

I always thought that many `try {...} catch(...) {...} ...` sections of code were an indicator of bad code design. I know that various Java classes require try-catch sections, but I didn't think that catching all (or many) possible exceptions was a part of good design.

Comment: That is more of a subjective discussion based upon the design of your application

Comment: You have to catch all exceptions that have a possibility of being thrown, obviously. Otherwise your program just crashes. You won't have that many try-catches usually though.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html and check out items 58 & 59 in Effective Java

Comment: Well, you have to catch (or list as thrown) all "checked" exceptions or your program won't even compile.  (Thank you Mr Goodenough!)

Comment: This comes down to opinion. I'm personally more inclined to check the inputs of a method and throw an exception if something will cause an exception. That way you don't have to deal with rolling back any state changes that might have happened before the exception was thrown. If there's an issue with your code that throws an exception, that's what a bug tracker is for. Then again, most of the coding I do is related to games, where it's faster/simpler to skip the thing that's causing an issue and log a warning. For more enterprise-y code, dealing with Exceptions is more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encounter any exception  and you don't handle it, your program is either doesn't compile or is blown at runtime. If you don't want many try catch statements, you can make a method declare some exceptions. But checked exceptions should always be handled in either way according to me.

Comment: Of course, generally one should avoid causing NullPointerExceptions in the the first place.

Comment: NPE's shouldn't be possible in the first place though, these are fairly easy to catch with some good coding practices and relevant tests.

Comment: @HotLicks Jeroen, I just wanted to give an example of exception. Nothing specific to NullPointerException.

Comment: One would not normally include a NPE try/catch in a program.

Comment: Only *checked* exceptions must be caught or listed in the `throws` clause.

Comment: @HotLicks I've removed the NullPointerException part from the answer.